# StringTokenizer to HashMap

Tags: java, строки, map

Уже несколько дней пытаюсь записать данные в `HashMap`.

Есть файл, из которого читаю `String` и разделяю его на части  `:`  вот таким делиметром. Файл состоит из слов и цифр (Пример: `2.0:Блонд:3.0:Лайт Блонд` ), цифры должны быть ключем и слова значением.

Comment: Ну и как ты собираешься определять, какая цифра соответствует строке, если они у тебя разделены?

2.0  
Блонд  
3.0  
Лайт Блонд 

Вот что получилось. Этот одномерный массив из каши ты точно хочешь запихнуть в карту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кто тебе дал такой уродливый формат данных? Делить ключи со значениями тем же делиметеров что и сущности. Бред. Вот как надо:

```
static public Map<Double, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void divide(String row) {
        String[] entry = row.split(":");
        map.put(Double.parseDouble(entry[0]), entry[1]);
    }
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    String[] ar = "2.0:Блонд;3.0:Лайт Блонд".split(";");
    for (String x : ar) {
        divide(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

эм, в чем проблема-то?

```
package name.etki.playground;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class SimpleParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "2.0:Bonnie:3.0:Clyde";
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        String[] chunks = input.split(":");
        if (chunks.length % 2 != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input is malformed, one pair is split");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < chunks.length; i += 2) {
            map.put(chunks[i], chunks[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```